# I want to open a popup window from jsf page without affecting the parent window functionalities

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

I want to put a two similar kind of links in existing page, both links are pop up new window and result from bean action will display in new pop up windows.

Case 1: Working fine if I put only 1st link.

Case 2: If I put 2nd link, 1st link is working fine but 2nd link not working as expected. not executing it's action and opening pop up with parent content instead of executing action and displaying the result in pop up.

Case 3: Working fine if I put only 2nd link.

Also it should not effect on my parent window's other links.(With the below code seems parent window is working fine) below is the my code snippet.

> Link1

```
<h:commandLink value="View Popup" styleClass="someClass" rendered="#{bean.isRenderTrue}"
target="popUpWindow1" binding="#{bean.popupLink1}"
onclick="javascript: void window.open('', 'popUpWindow1', 'width=780,height=450,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');"
action="#{bean.loadInPopUpWindow1}">
<f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
<f:param name="name" value=""/> 
</h:commandLink>
```

> Link2

```
<h:commandLink value="View Popup2" styleClass="someClass" rendered="#{bean.isRenderTrue}"
   target="popUpWindow2" binding="#{bean.popupLink2}"
   onclick="javascript: void window.open('', 'popUpWindow2', 'width=780,height=450,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');"
       action="#{bean.loadInPopUpWindow2}">
<f:param name="id" value=""/>
<f:param name="name" value="#{bean.name}"/> 
</h:commandLink>
```

Java bean action is

```
public String loadInPopUpWindow1() {
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
try {
List<UIComponent> children = popupLink1.getChildren();
    Map<String, List<String>> parameters = getParameters(children);
    String id = null;
    String name= null;
    if(parameters != null && parameters.size() > 0){
        List<String> ids= parameters.get("id");
        List<String> names = parameters.get("name");
        if(ids != null && ids.size() > 0) id = ids.get(0);
        if(names != null && names.size() > 0) name = names.get(0);
    }
    // Process the data and generate my view here which I want to display in popup

    String url = fc.getExternalContext().encodeActionURL(fc.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()+"/common/jsp/content/mypopup.faces");
    fc.getExternalContext().redirect(url);

} catch (IOException e) {
    fc.addMessage(popupLinkPkg.getClientId(fc), new FacesMessage("The link could not be redirected.", e.getMessage()));
}
return null;
}
```

Similarly loadInPopUpWindow2() method..

Need solution for Case2, Thanks in advance.